# Query optimization vtiger lead details

Tags: query-optimization, crm, vtiger

I am new to use vtiger crm. I am using vtiger 6.0 version. i am creating API.
Vtiger table: vtiger_leaddetails have almost 7 lacks records and i am running query below: It is taking almost 30 sec to give response. can anybody help me how can i optimize this query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(
    CASE WHEN (
      crm1.`createdtime` BETWEEN '2017-02-02' 
      AND '2017-03-18'
    ) THEN 1 END
  ) AS `'number_of_leads'`, 
  COUNT(
    CASE WHEN (
      vtiger_leaddetails.`current_status` = 'Consent Provided' 
      AND vtiger_leaddetails.`leadactivitystartdate` BETWEEN '2017-02-02' 
      AND '2017-03-18'
    ) THEN 1 END
  ) AS `'number_of_sales'`, 
  vtiger_leaddetails.`plan_name` AS `'plan_name'`, 
  plan.`plan_name_short` AS `'plan_name_short'`, 
  ROUND(
    (
      (
        COUNT(
          CASE WHEN (
            vtiger_leaddetails.`current_status` = 'Consent Provided' 
            AND vtiger_leaddetails.`leadactivitystartdate` BETWEEN '2017-02-02' 
            AND '2017-03-18'
          ) THEN 1 END
        )
      ) * 100
    ) / COUNT(vtiger_leaddetails.lead_no), 
    2
  ) AS `'ratio_of_conversion'`, 
  ROUND(
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN (
        vtiger_leaddetails.`current_status` = 'Consent Provided' 
        AND vtiger_leaddetails.`leadactivitystartdate` BETWEEN '2017-02-02' 
        AND '2017-03-18'
      ) THEN vtiger_leaddetails.`plan_price` END
    ) / 100000, 
    2
  ) AS `'revenu_in_lakh'` 
FROM 
  vtiger_leaddetails 
  INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity AS `crm1` ON crm1.crmid = vtiger_leaddetails.leadid 
  INNER JOIN oa_plan_master AS `plan` ON vtiger_leaddetails.`plan_id` = plan.`oasys_plan_id` 
  INNER JOIN vtiger_users AS `user_tab` ON user_tab.id = crm1.smownerid 
  INNER JOIN vtiger_campaign ON vtiger_campaign.campaignid = vtiger_leaddetails.campaign_name 
  INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity AS `crm2` ON crm2.`crmid` = vtiger_campaign.campaignid 
WHERE 
  vtiger_leaddetails.leadid > 0 
  AND crm1.`deleted` = '0' 
  AND crm2.`deleted` = '0' 
  AND plan.`deleted` = '0'
  AND vtiger_leaddetails.converted = 0 
  AND (
    (
      crm1.createdtime BETWEEN '2017-02-02' 
      AND '2017-03-18'
    ) 
    OR (
      vtiger_leaddetails.`leadactivitystartdate` BETWEEN '2017-02-02' 
      AND '2017-03-18'
    )
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  vtiger_leaddetails.`plan_id`
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Try to add indexes on related columns in the database

Comment: I have already did indexing to the related columns. I am trying any alternate solution to avoid select from vtiger_leaddetails table because it has records almost 20 lacks. If you have any idea please share.